# How to resolve conflicts when two binaries have the same name

Tags: linux, macos, ffmpeg, xampp, head

Running OS X (10.9), I have a program called 'HEAD' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/, which is related to libwww-perl.

The OS also has an unrelated program called 'head' in /usr/bin/

Since the filesystem is not case-sensitive, and both of these directories are in my PATH, there is a conflict.  I notice when I compile ffmpeg, it's using the xampp program when it should be using the OS program, and that's causing errors.

Comment: Change PATH temporarily, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

This is [a known problem](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.libwww/2002/10/msg4199.html) with case-insensitive HFS+ file systems. You're lucky you didn't overwrite `head` while installing LWP.

Two solutions:

- Put `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin` into the PATH at a later stage. The system-default `head` will take precedence. Refer to `HEAD` with its full path if you must, or create a shell alias for it.
- You should be able to rename `HEAD` into something else and just use that instead, depending on what calls it.

Comment: I did rename HEAD, but I don't know if this will cause problems. It's part of the default XAMPP installation, so I have no idea when it would be called.

Comment: Do you necessarily have to have the `bin` in your PATH? AFAIK only `xamppfiles/xampp` is the executable you'd really need.

Comment: I really don't know, that's a question for the XAMPP developers.  There are lots of binaries in there.  Since the default XAMPP installer adds this directory to the PATH, I would guess that their code does not use hard-coded paths to binaries.

Comment: Has anyone figured out what XAMPP actually uses its `HEAD` program for?  I was very confused when I tried to `head` a file today and got a help dialog about HTTP requests.